# How to calculate vector pairwise comparisons using ifesle function

Tags: r, if-statement

I need to calculate all pairwise difference for many variables (there are 100 in my dataset).
If the abs difference is >1 then it should appear 1, otherwise the result should be 0.
Then I want to summarize the 1 and 0 values for each of the pairwise comparisons and arrange them into a matrix.
I have tried the following code but there is an error message.

```
 juan<-outer(seq_along(rio_csv), seq_along(rio_csv), FUN =
  Vectorize(function(i, j)(sum(ifelse(abs(rio_csv[[i]]-rio_csv[[j]]))>1,1,0))))
```

The operation works well for two columns though.

```
> (pri<-sum(ifelse(abs(rio_csv$V1-rio_csv$V2)>1,1,0)))
```

data
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide a little bit of sample data - either a built-in data set (e.g., `mtcars`, if that is "close enough") or a copy/pasteable sample of your real data (e.g., `dput(rio_csv[1:6, 1:5])` for the first 6 rows of the first 5 columns).

Comment: Also, instead of saying "there is an error message", please put the error message in your question. They are often very useful.

Comment: As for your error message, it seems to be a misplaced `)`. Change `(sum(ifelse(abs(rio_csv[[i]]-rio_csv[[j]]))>1,1,0))))` to `(sum(ifelse(abs(rio_csv[[i]]-rio_csv[[j]])>1,1,0)))))`

Comment: As a minor note, you can `sum` or `mean` TRUE/FALSE values and TRUE will be treated as 1, FALSE as 0, so the `ifelse` is unnecessary in your code. You can simplify to `sum(abs(rio_csv[[i]] - rio_csv[[j]]) > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
a = 3*runif(100) # I'm just randomizing values, your dataset should come here

b = expand.grid(a,a) #also 'merge' would work
b$digital = 0
b$digital[abs(b[,1]-b[,2])>1] = 1 
result = b$digital
```

I don't know what you meant by putting values into matrix, but the 0/1 values are in the result variable (in a vector form still).
This is by no means the simplest and smoothest solution though, just a fast one:)
Also I didn't use ifelse function, but abs(b[,1]-b[,2])>1 is a boolean vector and the final result is same as with ifelse function..

Answer (score 0):

Using `mtcars` as example data, I'd do it like this:

```
data = mtcars

col_pairs = combn(names(data), 2, simplify = TRUE)

counts = apply(col_pairs, MARGIN = 2, function(x) sum(abs(data[[x[1]]] - data[[x[2]]]) > 1))

result = matrix(
  NA,
  nrow = ncol(data), ncol = ncol(data),
  dimnames = list(names(data), names(data))
)

result[t(col_pairs)] = counts
result
#      mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
# mpg   NA  32   32 32   32 32   27 32 32   32   32
# cyl   NA  NA   32 32   21 30   32 32 32   20   30
# disp  NA  NA   NA 32   32 32   32 32 32   32   32
# hp    NA  NA   NA NA   32 32   32 32 32   32   32
# drat  NA  NA   NA NA   NA 16   32 32 32    3   19
# wt    NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   32 28 28   17   19
# qsec  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA 32 32   32   32
# vs    NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA  0   32   20
# am    NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   32   21
# gear  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   14
# carb  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
```